# creating new Javascript objects in angular4/typescript sending json receving json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

This is going to be a long post but I need to be clear in my understanding of communicating between my server and client.

say I have a variable called  `cityList:City[] = [];` , and it is designed to contain a list of cities.

```
The model for `City` is:

    export class City{
  public name: string;

  constructor(name:string){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I have a api call that is designed to return a list of cities. This service has my generic getService injected into it (getservice below):

```
getService(url) {
    var value: any[] = [];
    this.http.get(url)
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          const data = response.json()
            .subscribe(
              (mappedData: any[]) => value = mappedData,
              (error) => console.log(error)
            )
              }
      );
    return value;
```

The service that will act on the data:

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {City, Neighborhood, Cuisine, Privacy, VenueType, Amenities } from
import {ServerComService} from "./serverComService";
import {cityListUrl, venueFilterDataOptionsUrl} from 'app/backendUrls';

@Injectable()
export class DynamicFormDataService implements OnInit {

  constructor(private serverComService: ServerComService){}

  cityList: City[]= [];
  neighborhood = [];
  cuisine = [];
  privacy = [];
  venueType = [];
  amenities = [];



  cityGet(){

    if(this.cityList.length > 0 ){
      return this.cityList;
    }
    this.cityList = this.serverComService.getService(cityListUrl)
    return this.cityList;
  }

 ngOnInit(){
    this.cityGet();
}
```

}

there are some typos in the imports but lets ignore them this is me just working on understanding first.

when I want to use the data in the `cityList` array is it just iterating through and calling that array positions city.name value?

what about if I wanted to add to the city list array?

I would have to call the city constructor, 
so perhaps a function that takes form data as its arguments, then

```
c = new City('Pound Town');
cityList.push(c);
```

then a service which called the push or put http method depending on if I am updating or creating a new.

The main and total question is then, is there anything I am missing in this process that skips transforming 
Json into Javascript objects

or javascript objects to Json?

Or am I correct in my overall execution? Does setting the type of variables take the strings of json and transform them into the proper types for the objects to be used in my client code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

(1) You cannot return the value if it is being fetched in an asynchronous operation (such as an http request).
You'll need to return a promise to the value instead of the value itself.
Something like:

```
getService(url) {
    this.http.get(url).then(response => {
        // transform response and return it
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

(2) Since `getService` is async, `cityGet` also can't return value, so maybe something like:

```
cityGet() {
    if(this.cityList.length > 0 ){
        return Promise.resolve(this.cityList);
    }

    return this.serverComService.getService(cityListUrl).then(response => {
        this.cityList = response;
    });
}
```

(3) In `getService` you receive a js object representing the json response, if you want to have instances of `City` then you need to create an instance of it per item in your result:

```
getService(url) {
    this.http.get(url).then(response => {
        return response.map(city => Object.assign(new City(), city));
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: if you will see though I subscribe to my observable before I return it, wouldn't that take care of the aysnc parts of it?

Comment: Nothing can "take care" of the async operation except for using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). In your code you are returning `value` before the response from the http request has returned and so `value` will have an empty array.

Comment: ah i see. so the subscribe would really be used in an example of me listing to a click button or an async task such as messaging updates.

Comment: but the promise would be used for when I am trying to populate a variable like I am here. And I can't return my code like you said because the code will execute while I am still waiting for the promise to fulfill correct? I need to study this more, I may have additional questions.

Comment: There can be many scenarios in which you'd use `subscribe`. But in this case it's not that you want to change the inner state, it's that you want to return the result of the operation, which is why you use a promise.

Comment: hold on one second though, what is the difference between the promise you wrote, and the observable that is subscribed in this example? It looks like they are both doing the same thing.

 `export class MyApp {
  private doctors = [];

  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
        .flatMap((data) => data.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
          this.doctors.push(data);

        });
  }
}`

Comment: There's no return value in this example. It is being done in the constructor, and the so the state of the instance will be changed once the response arrived. But in your code you want to return the result, not the same.

Comment: ok thats what I thought, but I wanted to ask it and here it explicitly. I am still learning this stuff and its a ton of information. Thank you man, so would it be better to instead subscribe elsewhere?

Comment: There's no better in this kind of thing, it depends on what you're trying to do and how you design your system.

Comment: what I mean, is instead of returning my values like I was subscribing to the observable I create in the serverComService my DynamicFormDataService

Comment: Yeah, I understood, but there's nothing wrong with using promises. Use whatever makes more sense for the design of your system